# How to simplify ffmpeg commands and efficiently?

Tags: ffmpeg

i'm quite new to ffmpeg and i've been learning how to make a 5 hour videos which loops for 5 hours and also add a intro video in the start of the video and at a outro/endscreen video at the end. I would like to know how i could do it more efficiently since i feel it's really taking a long time and too much work. My process and command's are as follows:

video specs: 3840x2160 , 60fps , 18M bitrate, hevc265

1. First i create a video of intro and outro/endscreen and save them as .mp4 format(both are 10secs long) using adobe premier.
2. i create a audio using adobe audition for the x amount of duration i want it to play, in this case 5 hours
3. I create the main video(which is 10 secs long) which i want to make it loop for 5 hours or any amount of time i want(this takes alot of time and is a huge file size and also adding name of the videos in the loop.txt etc video1.mp4, video2.mp4 till i reach to 5 hours), i use the command:
   ffmpeg -f concat -i loop.txt -c copy main5hours.mp4
4. Than i concat the intro,main,outro/endscreen videos together using:
   ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c copy videowithoutaudio.mp4
5. Than merge video and audio using:
   ffmpeg -i videowithoutaudio.mp4 -i audio.flac -c:v copy -c:a copy finalvideo.mp4

So this process takes a lot of time and file size and want some advice how i could do this more efficiently saving myself both time and file size and less work.

I read that i could also overlay the intro and endscreen videos but not sure how to do them and will it make any difference?
p.s: i'll be using the same intro and endscreen videos for all other videos i'll be making. Thanks in advance for any advice and help.

Comment: You can find information on how to improve the part 3, 4 and 5 of your pipeline here: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/repeat-loop-input-video-with-ffmpeg

Comment: Thats the method i'm already using and it does not mention anything about point 4 and 5. But it was a good read thank you